# Localize/Translate words on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

I am working on a Web site already developed in ASP.Net MVC 4,

Currently I am working on a task to Translate the site in different languages using Resources Files through Localization/Globalization techniques.

I have to call Resource file each time the word is used (as mentioned below) and it is working fine.

```
@***.******.UI.LocalResources.Resource.Change_Address
```

I want some technique to translate all words used in a web page automatically.

I've tried jQuery's document.ready() method (by getting list of all words in JS from Resource file) but invain, please guide me regarding any technique so that if a word is used at any place in a web page, it should be translated

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to abandon the plan to use resource files, and instead have all of the text translated automatically? Do you want to keep the resource files, but automatically translate them into every different language? Do you want to keep the resource files, but you're unsure how to approach switching languages? Do you want to keep using resource files, but your translation is not done yet, and you're looking for a technique to automatically move translatable strings into your resource files?

Comment: @Codebling I want to keep the resource files, and use em to find and translate all words of a view without calling it's resource file definition each time, e.g. there is a word "Change Address" on my view, which is used several times, I want it to be found & translated to other language without calling resources file object (@***.******.UI.LocalResources.Resource.Change_Address) each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you need. Also you can just put this box your page and it will translate everything.Its a great tool no hard coding.

[image]

Working Example *
https://repl.it/repls/SupportiveIncomparableLocation

Code from Gist * 
https://gist.github.com/joshuaaguilar20/f6054aa3e9e9ca48a91efff6b66e3848